# Set up a simple go server in a webhost

Tags: go, hosting, shared-hosting

I wanted to set up a simple go server in a webhost. I acquired a domain mydomain.com and hosted it using Bluehost. Now, going through the Go tutorial, I went through this example http://tour.golang.org/#59 and it works fine on my machine. Now, instead, I want to make the HelloWorldServer work when I call mydomain.com:4000 or some other port.

What I did was ssh to my server at bluehost, install go there, then compile the server and run. But then I try to access mydomain.com:4000 and it is not found. I also tried to change "localhost:4000" to just ":4000". any ideas how to make it work ?

Any help or pointers are appreciated. (some more details: it is a shared-hosting account)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the firewall on your BlueHost server not having ports (including 4000) open on a shared hosting account, [Firewall Port Restrictions](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/405)

If you want to do some simple (and not so simple) web hosting, why don't you look at [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/gettingstarted/introduction)

Comment: If you do upgrade to a dedicated/vps service the following article describes the steps you would take to open the ports. https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/minecraft

Comment: Another option is to use [Heroku](http://heroku.com/) as a hosting option, I've had great success with this in the past. Configuration instructions for getting Go applications to work with Heroku's platform can be [found here](http://mmcgrana.github.io/2012/09/getting-started-with-go-on-heroku.html)